# Pass data between third and first view controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, delegates

I got three view controllers, A, B and C.
A --modal--> B ---push --> C

How can I pass data from C --> A? I have tried using protocols and delegate. However my delegate method in A is never called.

Comment: You'll have to post some code or no one will be able to help you.

Comment: @jszumski: I dont have any code yet. My question is a theoretical one.
How can A know about data that is created in C, if A did not instantiate view controller C?

Comment: See my answer about using NSNotificationCenter below. Check the links for details to make sure that it will accomplish what you need done.

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly do this by using `NSNotificationCenter` see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17460980/trouble-saving-json-data-for-use-by-multiple-uiviews) where I had a similar problem. The question might not fully apply, but the answer holds a possible solution for you. Also read up [here](http://zeroheroblog.com/ios/notifications-in-ios-part-1-broadcasting-events-via-nsnotificationcenter) for more data.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use your AppDelegate to hold a reference for A, and than work from there on.

Answer (score 0):

You can store data in session (Create singleton object) and access it whatever you wish

```
@interface Session : NSObject

+(Session*) session;

@property (nonatomic) id data_to_access;

@end

@implementation Session
+(Session *)session
{
    static Session *sharedSingleton;

    @synchronized(self)
    {
        if (!sharedSingleton)
            sharedSingleton = [[Session alloc] init];

        return sharedSingleton;
    }
}
@end
```